# How can I completely remove wine?

Tags: apt, wine, uninstall

I'm trying to remove wine completely from Ubuntu.

I've already used several commands that say I no longer have wine installed, but when I run `sudo apt-get update` there are always remnants of wine.

```
Hit:1 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease
Get:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease [6,255 B]        
Ign:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu lunar InRelease                 
Hit:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu kinetic InRelease               
Err:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu lunar Release                   
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.66.217 443]
```

`sudo apt-get remove winehq-stable`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'winehq-stable' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Is this normal or is it because wine has not been completely removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you don't have wine installed, but you have added software sources for wine.

To remove them, open the `Software & Updates` program, go to the `Other Software` tab, and disable all sources related to Wine.

Finally run `sudo apt update`.

Answer (score 6):

From the details you posted, it does not appear that wine is currently installed.

However, you still have several software sources that you added to your system that are associated with wine.

This doesn't necessarily mean that wine is installed, but it does mean that you altered your system to allow software to be installed from these sources.

If you're no longer using the software from any of these sources, you should remove them.  You can disable them in the *Software & Updates / Other Settings* or you can manually delete them from `/etc/apt/sources.list` or possibly on other `.list` files in that directory or subdirectories.

It's worth pointing out that you made mistakes when you originally added this software. You added sources for multiple releases. (ie. eoan, lunar, and kinetic).  Never add sources that are for another Linux distribution or another version of Ubuntu. It can break your system. In general, take great care when adding sources. Adding sources fundamentally alters your system and if you add incompatible software it can break your system in a way that can sometimes be difficult to fix.  For more info, see: [Are PPAs Safe?...](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629). The advice there applies to any unofficial sources, not just PPAs.

Comment: Nice answer, and especially for the link to the question about PPA.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed. But I didn't manually set it, it must have been automatic. I don't have much experience with Linux.